# Creating CheckBox for JSON Objects

Tags: extjs4

I am using extjs4,I need to add check box group based on my JSON Object,

**JSON**

```
{"Provider":[{"id":3,"name":"Beta House","npi":0,"taxId":0,
    "address":{
        "state":{"id":"1","stateName":"Alabama","code":"AL"},
    "zipcode":0,"country":"USA","email":"beta@gmail.com"},
"type":"CP","LabProvider":[],"ListOfProvider":[]}]}
```

**ExtJs**
    Ext.define('providerList', {
                    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                    fields: ['id','name']
                });

```
            var provider = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'providerList',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : url+'/lochweb/loch/clinicalProvider/getAll',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'Provider'
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Panel**

```
 var checkboxconfigs = [];
                provider.each(function(record) { 
                    checkboxconfigs.push(
                            {                   
                                boxLabel: 'record.id', 
                                name: 'record.name'
                            }) 
                    });


var checkboxes = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({  
            fieldLabel:'Providers',  
            columns:2,  
            items:checkboxconfigs
             });

var patientProvider = new Ext.FormPanel({       
                renderTo: "patientProvider",
                frame: true,                 
                title: 'Association',
                bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',           
                width: 500,
                items: [{
                    checkboxes                               
                        }],                     
            });
```

There is no check box in the form.How to populate checkbox from JSON store

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `items` array before you use it as children of `checkboxes`. Each element of `items` array is created base on each record of the store.

```
var items = [];
provider.each(function(record) { items.push({boxLabel: 'up-to-you', name: 'up-to-you'}) }, );
var checkboxes = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({  
        fieldLabel:'Providers',  
        columns:2,  
        items:items
         });
```

Here you can determine the `boxLabel` and `name` for each checkbox (the attributes of `record` may be used as prefix, suffix...)

Comment: Hi Thanks for ue comment,i did as u suggested but it didnt works.The code is as follows,var items = [];
            provider.each(function(record) { 
                items.push(
                        {boxLabel: 'record.data.id', name: 'record.data.name'}
                        ) 
                });

Comment: items array is still empty after pusing box label and name.so there is no checkboxes in the form.

Comment: I have not the url to query, so I tried to add one record to the store and it works fine. Can you double-check the Ajax store? Does it have data after created?

Comment: Yes,data store is populated with JSON objects ,but checkboxes are not created

Comment: Really strange. It will work if the store has data. IMO, maybe you configure the store to query data using Ajax but actually it does not get data successful? By the way, the JSON returned should have the format of `{Provider:[{id:3,name:"Beta House",npi:0,taxId:0,  address:{state:{id:"1",stateName:"Alabama",code:"AL"}, zipcode:0,country:"USA",email:"beta@gmail.com"},
type:"CP",LabProvider:[],ListOfProvider:[]}]}`

Comment: Is there anythibg to change in datastore..??when i check the datastore as alert(provider),it shows [Object object]

Comment: `provider` is created as an object, but maybe it cannot get the data using the proxy. You should check whether it has data inside using `alert(provider.getAt(0))` or more specifically with `alert(provider.getAt(0).name)`

Comment: i tried as alert(provider.getAt(0).name) but it throws error as "There is no method called provider.getAt(0).name"

Comment: I mean: `provider.getAt(0)` is the data of first record of the store. You can assure that the store contains the data by alert anything of it, for examples: provider.getAt(0) == null, provider.getAt(0) == undefined, ...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

in the definition of panel items remove {} around checkboxes, like this:

```
                items: [ checkboxes ]
```

second, make sure that the store is available when you are populating checkboxes.

I have a similar situation in my app where store is available after panel is rendered. Panel is dynamically populated with list of checkboxes like this:

```
    panel.add(new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
        columns: 1,
        vertical: true,
        items: checkItems
    }));
    panel.doLayout();
```

EDIT: another tip:

remove qutoes '' from this code:

```
{                   
    boxLabel: 'record.id', 
    name: 'record.name'
}
```

or you will end up with all labels 'record.id'

Comment: I have run the code with changes I mentioned above and it works for a static store. Are you sure store is populated when you call 'each' on it?

Comment: try console.log for every record when you are calling 'checkboxconfigs.push' and check if records look ok.